# Using dt.truncate in a dataframe where duration is a column in the dataframe?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a dataframe, for example:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": ["a", "b"] 
        ,"event_timestamp": ["2023-07-01T01:14:05Z", "2023-07-01T07:50:36Z"]    
        ,"freq": ["15", "5"]
    }
)
df = df.with_columns(
    event_timestamp = pl.col("event_timestamp").str.strptime(pl.Datetime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    ,freq = pl.duration(minutes="freq")
)
```

which gives me this dataframe:

| id (str) | event_timestamp (datetime) | freq (duration) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2023-07-01 01:14:05 | 15m |
| b | 2023-07-01 07:50:36 | 5m |

I want to truncate the event timestamp using the freq as duration, like this:

```
df = df.with_columns(
    event_timestamp_truncated = pl.col("event_timestamp").dt.truncate(pl.col("freq"))
)
```

However I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'days'

Any thoughts?
Thank you

Was expecting the datimecolumn to be truncated using the value from keys. Error instead.

Comment: It doesn't look like [`dt.truncate`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.dt.truncate.html#polars.Expr.dt.truncate) takes Expression input. This could be a feature request.

Comment: You may have already been notified, but this has been merged and will be in `0.19.4` - https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/11155 - Perhaps you can add an answer showing the new functionality.

Comment: Yes, thanks, awesome. First time a feature request of mine gets implemented #msftdoesnotlistentome

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in comments, `dt.truncate` doesn't take an expression for the `every` parameter.

As such you'll have to use the dreaded `map_elements` to make the frequency into a python object.

```
(df
 .with_columns(
     truncs=pl.struct('event_timestamp','freq')
     .map_elements(lambda x: 
         pl.select(
            pl.lit(x['event_timestamp'])
            .dt.truncate(x['freq'])
            ).item()
        )
     )
 )
```

Comment: Thanks, I posted a feature request for this as well!